# Android Studio crashes when using adapter and background gradient color

Tags: android, background, crash, adapter, gradient

When I use background gradient color together with an adapter the application crashes. When I change the background color to a simple one (such as   android:background="@color/blueLgt") - no crash, or when I comment the setAdapter() method. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the test application:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package ...mylistview;

import (...)

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[]  myStringArray={"A","B","C"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new
            ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            myStringArray);

    ListView myList=(ListView)
            findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:background="@drawable/gradient_blue"

android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**drawable/gradient_blue.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/blueMed"
    android:centerColor="@color/blueLgt"
    android:endColor="@color/blueMed"
    android:angle="90">
</gradient>
</shape>
```

**CatLog**

```
07-26 22:51:08.050      656-656/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-26 22:51:08.130      656-663/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
07-26 22:51:08.150      656-663/? W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 20ms
    --------- beginning of crash
07-26 22:51:08.160      656-656/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: il.co.talkie.mylistview, PID: 656
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{il.co.talkie.mylistview/il.co.talkie.mylistview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at il.co.talkie.mylistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at il.co.talkie.mylistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/gradient_blue.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02003b
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2479)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at il.co.talkie.mylistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:404)
            at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.updateGradientDrawableGradient(GradientDrawable.java:1323)
            at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflateChildElements(GradientDrawable.java:1176)
            at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:1019)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at il.co.talkie.mylistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-26 22:51:44.760      656-663/il.co.talkie.mylistview W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10ms
```

Comment: post a complete stack trace from logcat

Comment: These are just random lines from your logcat. You need to run the app, cause it crash, and find the stack trace of the exception at the time of the crash. It should be very obvious which lines refer to the crash.

Comment: I am having troubles to load the catlog. hopefully the above is OK otherwise can you explain to me were can I find an explanation on how to understand the catlog

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:
From logcat I saw that the problem is because of a null object in the setAdapter() method. I added a check for null object after the creation of myAdapter and it was not null. Then I added a check for null object after the line
        ListView myList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
and myList was null. checking the xml file of the layout revealed that the obect id was listView2 and not listView. changed it and problem solved.
Nothing to do with the adapter or gradient background.
Thanks Karakuri for pointing me to look at the catlog.